# MDX CountDistinct calculated member by filtered attribute dimension

Tags: filter, count, distinct, mdx

I'm pretty new to MDX and I want to write following SQL Statement into MDX

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [DESC_Charm])as total
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[tbl_Charm] 
  WHERE ([DESC_Status] = 'solved'
  OR [DESC_Status] = 'terminated'
  OR [DESC_Status] = 'validated')
```

I tried this in MDX to get this as a calculated Member:

```
SUM(
{   [D Status].[DESC Status].&[solved],
    [D Status].[DESC Status].&[terminated],
    [D Status].[DESC Status].&[validated]
}
,[Measures].[F_CountDistinct_CHARMS]
)
```

However this statement sometimes counts to much, when i aggregate by Date over calendar weeks or months ... it only works correctly on my deepest aggregation level like days

What i need is a DistinctCount statement which is filter by attribute dimensions and also can be used by aggregation

Can someone give me an advice how to solve this ?

Comment: it seems that the soultion to my problem was quite simple ... instead of using the SUM function the Aggregate function seems to do it

Comment: can you post your solution here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe he means that simply replacing the `SUM()` function with `AGGREGATE()` solved the problem. This is because all the members are of the `[D Status].[DESC Status]` attribute.

```
Aggregate(
{   [D Status].[DESC Status].&[solved],
    [D Status].[DESC Status].&[terminated],
    [D Status].[DESC Status].&[validated]
}
,[Measures].[F_CountDistinct_CHARMS]
)
```

Since the measure is a distinct count already, the filter if needed in SSAS as an OLAP cube calculated member this could be obtained with

```
(
   [D Status].[DESC Status].&[solved],
   [D Status].[DESC Status].&[terminated],
   [D Status].[DESC Status].&[validated],
   [Measures].[F_CountDistinct_CHARMS]
)
```